# How can I use Pandas to replace same data string in meaning ( but typed differently ) and convert the minor in number into the major string

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining, data-cleaning

For example,

I have a large dataset with many attributes. Assuming one of the column is occupation column with 20 labels. Lets take one label , 1st Officer Engineer.

Since the dataset is structured, and due to the nature of how the data was collected, for occupation 1st Officer Engineer will be seen in many forms such as "First Office Engineer", "1st Off. Engineer".

My question is, what is the best approach for me to rename all of 1st Officer Engineer (including other versions) into one common version with Python. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First you can create the dictionary like:

```
di = {"First Office Engineer": "1st Officer Engineer", "1st Off. Engineer": "1st Officer Engineer", "1st Officer Engineer":"1st Officer Engineer"}
```

and simple map the values in pandas:

```
df.test.map(di)
```

where

> test

is the name of column.